# Solidity: Indexed expression has to be a type, mapping or array (is function (address,uint256) returns (bool))

Tags: solidity

```
     * @param value The number of tokens to be spent.
     */
    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) returns (bool) {
        require(spender != address(0));
        approve[spender][msg.sender] = value; // approve used to be _allowed?
        emit approve(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;
    }
```

receive error >Indexed expression has to be a type, mapping or array (is function (address,uint256) returns (bool))

Comment: please share the full code

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a function named `approve`, but then you're trying to access a mapping named `approve` as well.

Solution: Rename the mapping to use a different name (both the definition and its reference).

Answer (score 0):

The error means you are trying to use indexed epression as it were a mapping but it is defined as a function instead. Also in your code instead of "return true"  put>> "return false"